# Merging multidimensional array, then sorting by second level items

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date-sorting

So I've got these fun multidimensional arrays that I need to merge and sort.

Here's an example...

```
$arr1 = array(
    array(
        'date' => '2014-08-14 18:07:28',
        'message' => "Hi there!"
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2014-08-14 17:07:28',
        'message' => "Hi there!"
    )
);

$arr2 = array(
    array(
        'date' => '2014-08-14 18:01:28',
        'message' => "Hi there!"
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2014-08-14 11:07:28',
        'message' => "Hi there!"
    )
);
```

And I need to sort them by the date with the most recent at item 0 in the new array.

Been trying this with usort and a custom function, but haven't had a whole lot of luck.

Here's what I've got as the custom function right now.

```
function compareDate($ad, $bd) 
{
    $ad_time = strtotime($ad['date']);
    $bd_time = strtotime($bd['date']);
    return ($ad_time - $bd_time);
}
```

What can I do to improve this function?

Here's where I'm merging and sorting.

```
$mergedarray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
usort($mergedarray, 'compareDate');
```

Comment: Are you using `usort`? Can you include this code?

Comment: Just added my usort to the post.

Comment: What are your current results? To try: as you are using human being format for the date (and not a weird mid-endian thing), try to use the str_comp function as the example #2 at http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Your code works just fine in my tests after I fixed all the variable names (arr1 vs. array1, etc). I would make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on (*including notices!*) to ensure you're not mixing up variables or operating on empty things.

Comment: Maniac, I just changed the variable names in my code in the post because it would have just been weird looking. Strange that it was working for you. I'll try and get an output of what it was giving me.